# Use apollo-link-state to inject data into an ApolloLink Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I stored my token to authenticate with my GraphQL API by adding a JWT to the header inside an `apollo-link-state`s `@client` property.

```
  query ClientToken() {
    clientToken @client
  }
```

I now want to use that token to authenticate my Apollo remote queries. Without using the local cache, doing the following works:

```
const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer GETMEATOKEN`
    }
  })
  return forward(operation)
})
```

I'm struggeling to find a way to query this locally stored token inside this operation to add it where currently `GETMEATOKEN` appears.

Anyone has a suggestion if/who to query for a locally stored property inside an ApolloLink?

Thanks for all suggestions

Comment: running into the same issue.  Did you ever find a good solution to this?